# How do I avoid using a while loop here?

Tags: sql, loops, stored-procedures, while-loop

As someone who has never gotten direction/instruction from anyone in SQL, I'd like to hear from you guys how the following query should have been made.  From what I hear, loops like this are a pretty awful way to do things.

I'm creating a table within my query from this:

```
DECLARE @maxReleases int
SET @maxReleases = 100000

DECLARE @RootReleases table (ReleaseId int, RootReleaseId int)

DECLARE @ctr int
Set @ctr = 1

WHILE(@ctr <= @maxReleases)
BEGIN
WITH cte_Releases
( 
  ReleaseId,
  Name, 
  ParentReleaseID

) 
AS( 
  SELECT  
   ReleaseId, 
   Name,
   ParentReleaseID

  FROM Releases
  Where ReleaseId = @ctr

 UNION ALL 

 SELECT  
  R.ReleaseId,
  R.Name,
  R.ParentReleaseID 
 FROM Releases R
 INNER JOIN cte_Releases ON cte_Releases.ParentReleaseID = R.ReleaseId
) 
INSERT INTO @RootReleases 
SELECT max(ReleaseId) as ReleaseId, min(ReleaseId) as RootReleaseId FROM cte_Releases

SET @ctr = @ctr + 1
END
```

The purpose of this code is to build a table connecting records with their furthermost parent record, and insert it into a table to be referenced elsewhere in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have data to test so tell me What happens if you run something along these lines.
It should be possible using group by and aggregates.
If you provide sample data i may be able to help more.

```
     DECLARE @RootReleases table (ReleaseId int, RootReleaseId int)

;  WITH cte_Releases
( 
  ReleaseId,
  Name, 
  ParentReleaseID

) 
AS( 
  SELECT  
   ReleaseId, 
   Name,
   ParentReleaseID

  FROM Releases
 -- Where ReleaseId = @ctr

 UNION ALL 

 SELECT  
  R.ReleaseId,
  R.Name,
  R.ParentReleaseID 
 FROM Releases R
 INNER JOIN cte_Releases ON cte_Releases.ParentReleaseID = R.ReleaseId
) 
INSERT INTO @RootReleases 
SELECT max(ReleaseId) as ReleaseId, min(ReleaseId) as RootReleaseId FROM cte_Releases
WHERE ReleaseId BETWEEN 1 AND 100000
GROUP BY ReleaseId
```